# Replace or remove certain characters of string in a R data frame column from lookup table

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have a dataset with unique IDs and a corresponding path field where the path is a sequential number of events (think: purchased item1, item2, item3).

Here is some code to develop some simple sample data:

```
PathStackOverflow <- c("a,b,c","b,c","a,d,e","d,c","e","a,e","a,b,c,e")
PathStackOverflow
[1] "a,b,c"   "b,c"     "a,d,e"   "d,c"     "e"       "a,e"     "a,b,c,e"
PathID <- c(123,144,156,133,153,122,169)
PathID
[1] 123 144 156 133 153 122 169
StackOverflowDF <- cbind(PathID,PathStackOverflow)
StackOverflowDF <- data.frame(cbind(PathID,PathStackOverflow))
View(StackOverflowDF)


PathID PathStackOverflow
1    123             a,b,c
2    144               b,c
3    156             a,d,e
4    133               d,c
5    153                 e
6    122               a,e
7    169           a,b,c,e
```

The actual data frame has ~350,000 observations so it would be great if there's a computationally quick solution!

Some of the path values (e.g. a or e) need to be totally deleted based off a look up table. For example, let's say I want to remove all records with b  and d above. I want to define a vector for b and d and then remove all instances of that from the column so the end result looks like:

```
 PathID PathStackOverflow
1    123             a,c
2    144               c
3    156             a,e
4    133               c
5    153               e
6    122             a,e
7    169           a,c,e
```

It's important that the integrity of the column and dataframe is conserved because the next step is a cSplit where I'm splitting out the path by the comma and running some probabilities and frequencies of the appearance of each value.

So far, I've tried to do a horrible inefficient series of steps:

1. using grepl in ifelse to flag records for each instance where a path
   value needs to be deleted
2. then running cSplit to split out into several columns I've tried to do row level split/combine operations with plyr to find if columns in each row has the value and if so, delete them and recombine that row on the original.

But haven't been able to figure it out. Besides I think this approach is not efficient and there has to be a way to do delete the strings from the original, concatenated column.

Also tried the Gsub approach:

```
StackOverflowDF$ID <- gsub(',+b', '', StackOverflowDF$PathStackOverflow)
StackOverflowDF$ID <- gsub('b+,', '', StackOverflowDF$PathStackOverflow)
```

This seemed to work better but then my code is inefficient as I'm having to copy paste multiple lines for each char I want to remove and for every comma combo.

**I'm thinking the right solution would be some sort of helper function that can take the vector of strings to remove e.g. RemoveChars <- c("b","d") and then perform the gSub actions for each type of comma combo? Not sure if that's the best way to proceed and even if it is, how to loop through each look up table value.**

Would appreciate any help on how to proceed with this.

Comment: like this? `lookup <- c('b','d'); gsub(paste0(paste0(lookup, ','), collapse = '|'), '', PathStackOverflow)`

Comment: thank you for your help. Just curious, how does this do the look up for the presence of each value in the vector? I thought I would need to do a for loop to test each value through the column but this seems to be working on first glance..need to take another look to be sure though.

Comment: Was just thinking..I see this adds a pipe like the solution below. Perhaps Gsub has a means of "internally" looping through all strings separated by the pipe?

Comment: the pipe means "or" here

Comment: what is your lookup table?

Comment: I guess it's not a look up table, it's a vector that contains the letters/characters that I want to delete. e.g. RemoveChars <- c("b","d") except my actual one is RemoveChan <- c("Media One", "Tribal DisplayNet", "TV / Linear TV", "Holistic")

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try something like this

```
library(data.table)
PathStackOverflow <- c("a,b,c","b,c","a,d,e","d,c","e","a,e","a,b,c,e")
PathID <- c(123,144,156,133,153,122,169)
StackOverflowDT <- data.table(PathID,PathStackOverflow)

# Remove any unneeded values
StackOverflowDT[, PathStackOverflow := gsub("b|d", "", PathStackOverflow)]
# Remove any repeating commas
StackOverflowDT[, PathStackOverflow := gsub(",+", ",", PathStackOverflow)]
# Remove any beginning or ending commas
StackOverflowDT[, PathStackOverflow := gsub("^,|,$", "", PathStackOverflow)]

StackOverflowDT
   PathID PathStackOverflow
1:    123               a,c
2:    144                 c
3:    156               a,e
4:    133                 c
5:    153                 e
6:    122               a,e
7:    169             a,c,e
```

For a lookup table, you can easily extend the first `gsub`, with something along the lines of:

```
paste(c("b", "d", "someotherword"), collapse = "|")
```

If you haven't used `data.table` before I would definitely recommend the helpful documentation on the [github wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki).  Hope that helps.

Comment: would probably be safer to replace the first `gsub` with `gsub(, '(^|,)(b|d)(,|$)', '\\1\\3', ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `gsub` with a more general pattern:

```
df = StackOverflowDF  #sorry this is a long name

transform(df, new=gsub(',[b|d]|[b|d],','',df$PathStackOverflow))
#  PathID PathStackOverflow   new
#1    123             a,b,c   a,c
#2    144               b,c     c
#3    156             a,d,e   a,e
#4    133               d,c     c
#5    153                 e     e
#6    122               a,e   a,e
#7    169           a,b,c,e a,c,e
```

Comment: but b and d come from a lookup table so you need to make this scalable and generic

Comment: that `|` inside `[]` makes no sense; another problem is single letter cases, i.e. try it for "e"

Comment: @rawr this is trivial to extend to a lookup table, unfortunately this answer won't work for anything but letters, i.e. it won't work for words

Comment: @eddi I know it is trivial, I did it in a comment. doesn't change the fact that `but b and d come from a lookup table so you need to make this scalable and generic` thanks for your input, most helpful